# How to make Android App from existing JAva Code?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a multiplayer Chess program and I wanted to know if there is an easy way to make an app for it. If I worth with Android SDKs on Eclipse, do I have to code the whole thing again or I can just use the Java code for making the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what libraries you're using in your game and their support in Android.

If you use Java for the existing implementation, you'll hopefully, have to write the UI bits, and the erst of the logic should simply work.

If this is a desktop app you're trying to port, you may have performance issues (given you're running on a mobile device now), so there would be some changes necessary.

If you're using any graphics libraries, check their support on Android. Some libraries have a reputation of having issues on Android.

Comment: I have a complete app with UI and stuff which I have successfully deployed on app-engine. I want to make an android app for it now

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. You just need to insert your JS files or you could use the Url of your uploaded app.